# PostgreSQL: How do I set the search_path at the user level?

Tags: postgresql

I want to set the default search_path to something other than the "public" schema.
But I only want to do this for a particular user.
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I found the answer:

```sql
ALTER ROLE username SET search_path = schema1,schema2,schema3,etc;
```

Comment: ALTER USER has been deprecated in favor of ALTER ROLE

Comment: FYI, to make that setting specific to the user + database, use `alter role username IN DATABASE DATABASENAME set search_path = whatever`

Comment: I'm not sure if it's something I did wrong, but the '=' sign didn't seem to work for me in PSQL. When I used the keyword 'to' instead it seemed to work.

Comment: This post was useful. http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/279-Schema-and-search_path-surprises.html

Comment: do i need to restart postgres service for this to kick in?

Comment: log out / log in from PostgreSQL