# How to set schema in pg-promise

Tags: javascript, postgresql, pg-promise, node-postgres

I was searching the documentation of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) specifically in the creation of the client. But I wasn't able to find the option to set the default schema to be used in the connection, it always uses `public` schema. How do I set it?

Comment: Default schema is controlled by the server, not by the client, i.e. the library doesn't use `public` by default, it uses whatever is set as the default on the server.

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875610/permanently-set-postgresql-schema-path

Comment: You can set the schema search path at the user level: see answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951875/postgresql-how-do-i-set-the-search-path-at-the-user-level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951875/postgresql-how-do-i-set-the-search-path-at-the-user-level)

Comment: Ah that's why it's not in the connection parameters. Ok thank you. The link you sent me was really helpful also.So my solution was to set the schema on server start using the SET search_path query.

Comment: Alternatively, you can have the library inject the schema name automatically. See [pg-promise-demo](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally, one sets the default schema(s) for the database or the role, as explained here:

- [Permanently Set Postgresql Schema Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875610/permanently-set-postgresql-schema-path)

It is only if you want to do so without persisting the change, you might want to set the schema(s) dynamically, just for the current process.

The library supports option `schema` within [Initialization Options](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/module-pg-promise.html):

```
const initOptions = {
    schema: 'my_schema' /* can also be an array of strings or a callback */
};

const pgp = require('pg-promise')(initOptions);
```

making it easier to set the dynamic schema(s).

**Examples**

- Making your own schema visible along with the default `public` schema:

  ```
  const initOptions = {
      schema: ['public', 'my_schema'] /* make both schemas visible */
  };

  const pgp = require('pg-promise')(initOptions);
  ```
- Using the callback to set schema based on the Database Context (see [Database](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html) constructor):

  ```
  const initOptions = {
      schema(dc) {
          if(dc === /* whatever Database Context was used */) {
              return 'my_schema'; /* or an array of strings */
          }
          /* other provisions, if multiple databases are used. */

          /* can return null/undefined, if no schema change is needed. */
      }
  };

  const pgp = require('pg-promise')(initOptions);
  ```

Comment: Removed examples with the obsolete manual approach, for simplicity, and to avoid confusion. The new option `schema` should be used only.